# Substitute for Pressure-Treated 2x3

Tags: basement, framing, pressure-treated

I'm trying to replace a few sections of rotted bottom plate in my basement. I want to use pressure-treated lumber as it will be in contact with the concrete on 2 sides (and it still occasionally gets wet in one section, still trying to fix that,) but the basement was unfortunately framed in 2x3, and I can't find PT 2x3 anywhere nearby. Do I have any good options?

Some ideas:

Rip a PT 2x4 down to size.

Use regular 2x3s, and treat the contacting faces with Copper-Green preservative (I already have a quart lying around)

Use regular 2x3s, and wrap the contacting faces in sheet plastic.

Would any of these work, or is there a better option?

Comment: Option 1 (ripping a 2x4) is the simplest, cheapest, and most effective. Depending on the gap behind the wall you may not even need to rip it.

Comment: Yup, rip it and use your copper-napthenate to treat the cut face.